# C++ Polymorphism + template member function for selecting return type. How to do it?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, traits

I want to implement a class hierarchy for object dispatching. Different classes dispatch different elements, and each class can dispatch its element represented as different data types.

It is better understood through a (faulty) example. This is what I would like to have if virtual function templating was allowed:

```
class Dispatcher {
    template <class ReturnType>
    virtual ReturnType getStuffAs();
};
```

So that I can implement subclasses as:

```
class CakeDispatcher : public Dispatcher {
    template <>
    virtual Recipe getStuffAs(){ ... }
    template <>
    virtual Baked getStuffAs(){ ... }
};
class DonutDispatcher : public Dispatcher {
    template <>
    virtual Frozen getStuffAs(){ ... }
    template <>
    virtual Baked getStuffAs(){ ... }
}
```

So that I can do the following later on:

```
void function( Dispatcher * disp ) {
    // Works for Donut and Cake, but result will be a different Baked object
    Baked b = disp->getStuffAs<Baked>();
    // works if disp points to a DonutDispatcher
    // fails if it is a CakeDispatcher
    // can be compiling/linking time error or runtime error. I don't care
    Frozen f = disp->getStuffAs<Frozen>(); 
}
```

Requirements/constraints:

- All possible return types are not known beforehand. That's why I "need" templates.
- Each class can provide just some return types.
- Classes must have a common ancestor, so that I can store objects through a pointer to parent class and invoke functions through this pointer.
- **EDIT:** I CAN'T use C++11 features, but I CAN use boost library.

Things I've thought about, but are not a solution:

- Obviously, virtual template functions
- [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern): breaks the condition of common ancestor
- Using some kind of traits class containing the functionality of children classes, but it does not work because a non-virtual implementation in the parent class does not have access to this information

I could maybe store some typeid info in the parent class, passed by children on construction. This makes possible for the non-virtual parent dispatching method to dynamic-cast itself to the children type... but it appears to be ugly as hell, and I don't know if this can cause some kind cycle-referencing problem.

```
class Dispatcher {
private: 
    typeid(?) childType;
public:
    Dispatcher(typeid childT) : childType(childT) {}

    // NOT VIRTUAL
    template <class ReturnType>
    ReturnType getStuffAs()
    {
        // or something equivalent to this cast, which I doubt is a correct expression
        return dynamic_cast<childType *>(this)->childGetStuffAs<ReturnType>();
    }
};
```

Then child classes would implement childGetStuffAs functions, which are not virtual too.
I've read like 5-10 related questions, but none of the provided solutions seems to fit this problem.

Can any of you come up with a better solution? 
Is there a standard pattern/technique for solving this problem?

**EDIT: The real problem**
In the real problem, I have physical models with properties that can be represented in multiple ways: functions, matrices, probability distributions, polynomials, and some others (for example, a non-linear system can be represented as a function but not as a a matrix, while a linear system can be transformed to both).

There are also algorithms which can use those models indistinctly, but they could require specific representations for some model features. That's the reason for the "getStuffAs" function. The whole think is a bit complicated --too much to explain it here properly--, but I can guarantee that in this context the interface is well defined: input, computation and output.

My intention was to make this possible assuming that the number of possible representations is fully defined beforehand, and making it possible to transform the products to already existing types/classes that cannot be modified. 
However, i'm starting to realize that this is, indeed, not possible in a simple way --I don't want to write a library just for this problem.

Comment: template + virtual on function don't mix.

Comment: `Classes must have a common ancestor` So why not just use base pointers in your dispatcher?

Comment: So what should happen if someone requests a return type your class does not implement?

Comment: Neil: I don't understand your question about base pointers in the dispatcher :-(
n.m.: Either compilation error (if using static polymorphism or template stuff) or runtime error. Anyway, using traits can alleviate this problem.

Comment: I think your abstraction is wrong...In essence, there is no relationship between the interface in CakeDispatcher vs. DonutDispatcher. The only reason I can see to do this is to iterate over all the different dispatchers, in which case you should use a Tuple to collect the disparate types if the different Dispatchers are defined at compile time. If they are not, then there is no way for you to receive what these guys are outputting without serious reflection and duck typing capabilities of the language.

Comment: The receivers know exactly the output (remember I was interested in templating the call, p->getStuffAs<Type>()), but maybe my abstraction is wrong... the motivation is that receivers should be able to deal with different "information" providers, but they have restrictions on the type in which that info is represented. The interface is clear, though potentially infinite: "I want your info represented as X", and each provider can satisfy that request or not.

Anyway, aside from my motivations, I'm interested in knowing if it is possible to solve that problem in an elegant way.

Comment: @dunadar A clear interface defines inputs, what it does with the inputs, and the outputs. Your interface defines the first one well (takes in nothing), but does "smoke" and returns "smoke", and therefore is not clearly defined. The method "getStuffAs" is just as useless as `template <typename T> T foo();`. Without knowing more about the relationship between the returned types it'll be hard to solve this X vs. Y problem, but the short answer is "The thing above? That ain't gonna fly in a strongly typed language."

Comment: If you want compulation error then you have a contradiction right here. On one hand you want to store a pointer to a common ancestor, on the other hand you want children to have different interfaces, detectable statically. Not gonna happen.

Comment: OTOH if you want runtime errors it's almost too easy. A non-virtual template packs its argument into a derived class `Arg<T> : public BaseArg`, calls a virtual non-template that takes a `BaseArg*`, a dynamic cast, and voilà.

Comment: @IdeaHat I added an edit to the original question, just in case you are interested in knowing a bit about the real problem. Anyway, thank you for your help.
Regarding the last comment by n.m. (thank you too), I have also thought about passing type_infos as an argument, test runtime, and return data as boost::any.

Comment: In response to your edit with the real problem: have you considered using templates for your algorithms (instead of your physical models)?

Comment: @tecu (better late than never) yes, but it doesn't work because the algorithms must be exchangable on runtime :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstdio>
// as a type identifier
struct stuff {
    virtual void foo() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct stuff_inh : stuff {
};

struct Dispatcher {
    template <typename T>
        T* getStuffAs() {
            return (T*)((getStuffAsImpl( new stuff_inh<T>() )));
        }

    virtual void* getStuffAsImpl(void*) = 0;
    virtual void type() {printf("type::dispatcher\n");}
};

struct Cake : public Dispatcher {
    void* getStuffAsImpl(void* p) {
        stuff* s = static_cast<stuff*>(p);
        printf("cake impl\n");
        if (dynamic_cast<stuff_inh<Cake>*>(s) == NULL) {
            throw "bad cast";
        }
        return (void*)(new Cake());
    }
    virtual void type() {printf("type::Cake\n");}
};

struct Rabbit : public Dispatcher {
    void* getStuffAsImpl(void* p) {
        stuff* s = static_cast<stuff*>(p);
        printf("rabbit impl\n");
        if (dynamic_cast<stuff_inh<Rabbit>*>(s) != NULL) {
            return (void*)(new Rabbit());
        }
        else if (dynamic_cast<stuff_inh<Cake>*>(s) != NULL) {
            return (void*)(new Cake());
        }
        else {
            throw "bad cast";
        }
    }
    virtual void type() {printf("type::Rabbit\n");}
};

void foo(Dispatcher* d) {
    d->getStuffAs<Cake>()->type();
    d->getStuffAs<Rabbit>()->type();
}


int main() {
    Rabbit* r = new Rabbit;
    foo(r);
    Cake* c = new Cake;
    foo(c);
}
```

I an not sure about the correctness of this ugly solution, may it be helpful for you. >_<

deletion of resource is not coded for a clearer look.

Comment: At first glance, I think it's the same solution I've seen proposed for workarounding the virtual+template problem. You can also use boost::any in place of void * for type erasure.
It is a bit ugly, yes, but I think it could work. However, I don't like all those dynamic casts around... it is probably impossible to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is a combination of recurring template and diamond inheritance. 
At least it's working. :)

```
#include <iostream>

class Dispatcher
{
public:
  template<class T>
  T getStuff()
  {
    return T();
  }
};

template<class T>
class Stuffer : public Dispatcher
{
public:
  template<class TT=T>
  TT getStuff(){
    return reinterpret_cast<TT>(this);
  }
};

class Cake{
public:
  Cake(){}

  void print()
  {
    std::cout << "Cake" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Recipe
{
public:
  Recipe(){}

  void print()
  {
    std::cout << "Recipe" << std::endl;
  }
};

class CakeRecipe : public Stuffer<Cake>, public Stuffer< Recipe >
{
public:
};

int main()
{
  Dispatcher* cr = reinterpret_cast<Dispatcher*>(new CakeRecipe());
  cr->getStuff<Cake>().print();
  cr->getStuff<Recipe>().print();

  getchar();
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: This isn't doing what you think its doing. It is calling the dispatchers get-stuff method, which still can make the empty Cake and Recipe classes, which will still print correctly. The Stuffer method is never called. It is not the CRTP, and the diamond inheritance probably makes this whole thing useless without virtual inheritance.